# Could AWE or anything else could help to use more SQL memory

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, ram

I read multiple articles and Q&A about the SQL AWE option but I am still confuse.

Here is our situation:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bits
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bits
- 48 GB RAM physically on the server
- 32 GB RAM usable by the OS
- 24 GB RAM max sql server memory

Based on the current activity on that server, we need about 8 GB outside of SQL in order to be fine, so we max it at 24 GB.

I beleive the OS see only 32 due to the "standard" edition of window 2008 R2, am I right?

The AWE option is not enable in SQL Server, but would it make a difference since the OS is not even able to use the full 48GB ?

Is there anything else we could do to maximize the RAM on that server?

Any tips would be appreciate, thank you !

Comment: no, AWE does not need to be enabled. see http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-530-awe-must-be-enabled-on-64-bit-servers/

Comment: also, if the OS can only see 32 GB, then SQL will not be able to see beyond that either, because the OS is in charge of memory allocation.

Comment: So there's nothing I can do, except changing the version of the OS? (meaning to reinstall the whole server)

Comment: That's what it appears like to me. You can check over on http://serverfault.com/ for a second opinion if you like. They are more hardware focused than is site is.

Comment: According to https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/a9fb29a1-9cad-4d01-9e65-ce9b2b88232b/upgrade-from-server-2008-standard-to-server-2008-enterprise you can upgrade it...  Good luck!